# Using a pre-made complex cloud application for benchmarking

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

I am evaluating a few "cloud monitoring" tools. What ready-made complex applications can I deploy to AWS, to evaluate these tools? I am looking for something which automatically creates a multi-node LAMP stack, for example, or a Hadoop/Spark cluster.

**EDIT:** as an example, I'm looking for something like [CloudSuite](https://github.com/ParsaLab/cloudsuite), but that is meant to be deployed in a multi-host environment.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any premade complex setups that are turnkey and ready to go.  They all take some configuration.

You can setup some preconfiured LAMP servers from BitNami:

[LAMP powered by Bitnami](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B007IN7GJA)

You can then cluster them via an Elastic Load Balance and connect them to a RDS instance for few hours and run tests.

You can also review the [AWS Quick Start Reference Deployments](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/)

Another option would be to use [CloudFormation Sample Templates](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-sample-templates.html) to automate the setup of common services.